# PasteFromOffice Plugin not keeping the font size

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I have set up CKEditor5 and added the font plugin (@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font/src/font) as well as the PasteFromOffice plugin (@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paste-from-office/src/pastefromoffice). While pasting images from Word works nicely, the problem is the font size and font family values are not saved. For example, I don't get this 
`<p><span style="font-family:"Times New Roman",serif;font-size:28.0pt;">This is Very large Font</span></p>` 
but only get `<p>This is Very large Font</p>` 
I also have problem with pasting some symbols such as π or β. I have other plugins such as image upload, tables, working properly. What am I missing and how should I go about solving this problem?

Comment: can you tell me how to add plugin in this ck5 because i am trying autosave but it;s not working i have tried with npm also but then i have download it form GIT and added near the ck editor and add the js in the main file but still autosave plugin is not working

Comment: a similar issue discussed here [github](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/9421)